# Разница между двумя строками одной таблицы MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, в которую каждый день вставляется данные `val1` и `val2`

```
CREATE TABLE `TestTable` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_from` DATE,
  `val1` INT,
  `val2` INT,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

Как сделать запрос в таблице, чтобы вывести разницу (`val1` и `val2`) между самой первой и последней записью

К примеру

```
10 января val1 = 10, val2 = 7, 
20 февраля val1 = 15, val2 = 100
```

Мне нужен запрос который

1. выведет число дней между первой и последней датой (20 фев - 10 янв = х дней)
2. разница между `val1` (От 10 янв) и `val1` (от 20 февр) ... (15 - 10 = 5)
3. разница между `val2` (От 10 янв) и `val2` (от 20 февр) ... (100 - 7 = 93)

заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Разность дат:

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('1997-12-31 23:59:59','1997-12-30');
    -> 1
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('1997-11-30 23:59:59','1997-12-31');
    -> -31
```

Делайте в 2 запроса, намного лучше выйдет.

Вариант 1:

```
1)Получаем данные первые из таблицы(первая запись).
2)Получаем последние данные из таблицы.
3)Считаем нужную разницу.
```

Вариант 2:

```
select 
  datediff(g1.date_from,g2.date_from),
  g1.val1-g2.val1,
  g1.val2-g2.val2
from
  TestTable g1,
  TestTable g2
where
  g1.date_from=(select min(date_from) from testtable) and
  g2.date_from=(select max(date_from) from testtable);
```

По идее должно работать, хотя неуверен.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.val1-a.val1, b.val2-a.val2 from
(select val1, val2 from TestTable where date_from =
(select min(date_from) from TestTable)) a,
(select val1, val2 from TestTable where date_from =
(select max(date_from) from TestTable)) b
```

Но это только если date_from уникальны. Иначе уже бубен в руки.